# Opendaylight Integration with gns3

Tags: opendaylight

Does anyone tell me the proper integration of opendaylight with GNS3
Actually, I want to enable NETCONF in switch for that I use GNS3 but unable to find any proper document for GNS3 integration with opendaylight.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you check the videos by **David Bombal** on youtube or on Udemy. They provide great resource to integrate Opendaylight with GNS3.

Although I don't know what your project is all about, why not try using RYU controller instead?
I find RYU controller easire to use because of its use of python.